# How do I set a DynamicResource for color for a SolidColorBrush in code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml

I know that you can set a DynamicResource for a framework element using SetResourceReference. However, this doesn't seem to be available for a SolidColorBrush for setting the color dynamically. In XAML, I would just

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xxx" Color="{DynamicResource MyColor}"/>
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for it?